# Get files (in folder,subfolder from a drive) based on last access parameter in powershell

Tags: file, powershell, subdirectory

I want a script to list all files in folder/subfolder with a particular last access date.

I have a script to show a subfolder:

```
get-childitem -Recurse | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | select {$_.Fullname}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.lastaccesstime -ge [datetime]"12/18/11"} | select fullname
```

this give you a files's list with lastaccesstime attribute greater or equal 18 december 2011  00.00 am.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.lastaccesstime -ge [datetime]"12/01/11" -and $_.lastaccesstime -lt [datetime]"12/02/11"} | select fullname
```

this give all file with lastaccesstime in date december 01 2011 from 00.00am to 11.59pm

lastaccesstime is a complete reference to date and time, that's why you need to specifies a range for a single date match.

Comment: To check against just a date, you can also check equality against the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) value of [`LastAccessTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx): `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where { $_.LastAccessTime.Date -eq '2011-12-01' }`